# Проблема composer cache:clear в Docker for Windows

Tags: windows, docker, composer

При выполнении команды cache:clear после composer install вылезает ошибка

```
 ResolveBindingsPass.php line 84:

  A binding is configured for an argument named "$kernelEnvironment" for serv
  ice ".service_locator.hceZVHa" in file "/www/config/services/autowiring.yam
  l", but no corresponding argument has been found. It may be unused and shou
  ld be removed, or it may have a typo
```

Такое только при запуске docker for windows, wsl2.
На Ubuntu, MacOS все окей запускается